# Boolean (Difference) modifier gliched

Tags: modifiers

I am having problems where the boolean-difference modifier is not fully working on a few of my objects. You can see (↓) the weird thing computers do when two objects overlap (brown lines/splotches on the black background of the tubes, meaning that the brown block is in the same place as the black tube.
[image]

As you can see by the orange horizontal lines in x-ray mode (↓), the brown block is not fully being negated where the black tube is, but it works fine for the clear-ish tubes.
[image]

I am using the boolean modifier, set to difference, and I have done it for the 3 clear-ish tubes and the 3 black tubes.
The only advice i could get from other posts/websites was to fix the normals of the black tubes and check for duplicate edges/vertices, but I did both of those and it didn't change anything.

Here is the file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag953wi7X0D-gp0St8jGZNJrTrUc0w?e=9czZeN

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Boolean has 2 solver modes: _fast_ and _exact_ - have you tried the "other" one (compared to what you  are currently using)? Also, Booleans can be a bit finicky when it comes to position, sometimes moving the "cutter" object even as little as .001 units in any direction helps it make a more "sensible" subtraction.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - Switched from _exact_ to _fast_. The pattern of the brown lines changed but didnt fix anything.

Comment: Sorry.. I added to my comment. Did you see/try the second part?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett That didnt work either :(

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris I did above. Hopefully the link works